# Why does select count(*) give different result that select?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For the following query, I get 2000. But when I run the query inside the 
outer `select Count(*)` , it returns me 1100 records. Why is that?
Actual query had to be truncated due to StackOverflow whining about too much code.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (
SELECT Max(sequence) Sequence,
               Max(keycode)  Keycode,
               Min(dfo)      DFO,
               segmentid
        FROM ( SomeTable2) 
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1000 *
FROM SomeTable2
)
AS C
```

Comment: I don't see how that query runs at all as is.  You are selecting `segmentid` but not including it a `group by` clause.  Sample data, table structure, and expected results would be helpful...

Comment: `count(DISTINCT expression)` counts only each distinct occurrence of a value `expression` evaluates to. It does not count each row. There might well be a lot of rows in which `expression` evaluates to the same value. Then `count(DISTINCT expression)` < `count(*)`, which counts all rows.

Comment: Can you post BOTH queries? It would be much clearer.

Comment: @WebBoy: not true. You need to post more textual information, especially explanatory information if you are going to post a larger amount of code, and this is for darn good reason too.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels My description is adequate for the problem.  I would have to ramble about nothing to get enough text to satisfy stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

`Select count (*)` can admit repetitions or redundants columns that why you get more results but with `distinct` the count will only hive you the occurency of columns without repetitions.Example You have the following record in your table `a b c d e d` .With `select count(*)` you will get `6` but the letter `d` come 2 times but which `distinct` you will get `5` as it ignore the repeted record as it will ignore `d` become it's more than one time.

Comment: Even with Select count(*) it returns wrong count.  But if i do @@ROWCOUNT After i get correct answer, but that is a pain in neck